# Find the formula of the sum of the first n members of the following sequence:

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the formula of the sum of the first n members of the following sequence:

$ 1; 5 \times 3^2; 9 \times 3^4; ...; (4n-3)\times 3^{2n-2} $

Comment: That looks like an arithmetico-geometric sequence.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n(4k-3)3^{2k-2}&=\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)3^{2k-2}+3\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-2)3^{2k-3}\\&=\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{2k-1}\right)\right]_{x=3}+3\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{2k-2}\right)\right]_{x=3}\\&=\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x^2}\right)\right]_{x=3}+3\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^2}\right)\right]_{x=3}\end{align}$$
Now differentiate the expressions and evaluate the derivative at $x=3$.